# How to move a window to another screen with a different scale?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, position, scale

I have these two screens:

[image: Screen layout]

1. 1080p, 100% scale.

   1. Bound: {3840,0,1920,1080}
   2. Native bounds: {3840,0,1920,1080}
2. 4k, 200% scale, set as primary.

   1. Bounds: {0,0,1920,1080}
   2. Native bounds: {0,0,3840,2160}

---

Now, let's suppose that a multi-DPI aware app is displaying a window inside **screen 2**.

How to move that window to the top-left corner of the **screen 1**?

I don't want to limit to this configuration, since the user can add, remove, or reposition screens.

[image: Target position]

---

I understand that setting the `Left` and `Top` properties of a window is relative to the scaling of the window.

Setting `Left = 2000;` will translate to different positions depending on the scale of the window.

I already tried to set position to bounds of target screen, taking into consideration the difference in scale.

```
Left = nextScreen.NativeBounds.Left / (this.Scale() / nextScreen.Scale) + 30; 
Top = nextScreen.NativeBounds.Top / (this.Scale() / nextScreen.Scale) + 30;
```

For a window inside a 200% scale screen, the calculated `Left` of 1950 would translate into beyond 3840.

But it does not work. It positions the window in the middle-top position of the **screen 2**.

I don't see any other way of doing this without calculating the position based on the set of screens around, which can be complex if there's many of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to move the window with a simple *p/invoke* to `SetWindowPos`, passing the native bounds of the target window:

```
internal static class Windows
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Special window handles.
    /// </summary>
    internal enum SpecialWindowHandles
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Places the window at the top of the Z order.
        /// </summary>
        Top = 0,
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Places the window at the bottom of the Z order.
        /// If the hWnd parameter identifies a topmost window, the window loses its topmost status and is placed at the bottom of all other windows.
        /// </summary>
        Bottom = 1,
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Places the window above all non-topmost windows.
        /// The window maintains its topmost position even when it is deactivated.
        /// </summary>
        TopMost = -1,
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Places the window above all non-topmost windows (that is, behind all topmost windows).
        /// This flag has no effect if the window is already a non-topmost window.
        /// </summary>
        NoTopMost = -2
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// If the calling thread and the thread that owns the window are attached to different input queues, the system posts the request to the thread that owns the window.
        /// This prevents the calling thread from blocking its execution while other threads process the request.
        /// </summary>
        AsyncWindowPositioning = 0x4000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Prevents generation of the WM_SYNCPAINT message.
        /// </summary>
        DeferErase = 0x2000,

        /// <summary>
        /// Draws a frame (defined in the window's class description) around the window.
        /// </summary>
        DrawFrame = 0x0020,

        /// <summary>
        /// Applies new frame styles set using the SetWindowLong function.
        /// Sends a WM_NCCALCSIZE message to the window, even if the window's size is not being changed.
        /// If this flag is not specified, WM_NCCALCSIZE is sent only when the window's size is being changed.
        /// </summary>
        FrameChanged = 0x0020,

        /// <summary>
        /// Hides the window.
        /// </summary>
        HideWindow = 0x0080,

        /// <summary>
        /// Does not activate the window.
        /// If this flag is not set, the window is activated and moved to the top of either the topmost or non-topmost group (depending on the setting of the hWndInsertAfter parameter).
        /// </summary>
        NoActivate = 0x0010,

        /// <summary>
        /// Discards the entire contents of the client area.
        /// If this flag is not specified, the valid contents of the client area are saved and copied back into the client area after the window is sized or repositioned.
        /// </summary>
        NoCopyBits = 0x0100,

        /// <summary>
        /// Retains the current position (ignores X and Y parameters).
        /// </summary>
        NoMove = 0x0002,

        /// <summary>
        /// Does not change the owner window's position in the Z order.
        /// </summary>
        NoOwnerZOrder = 0x0200,

        /// <summary>
        /// Does not redraw changes. If this flag is set, no repainting of any kind occurs.
        /// This applies to the client area, the nonclient area (including the title bar and scroll bars), and any part of the parent window uncovered as a result of the window being moved.
        /// When this flag is set, the application must explicitly invalidate or redraw any parts of the window and parent window that need redrawing.
        /// </summary>
        NoRedraw = 0x0008,

        /// <summary>
        /// Same as the NoOwnerZOrder flag.
        /// </summary>
        NoReposition = 0x0200,

        /// <summary>
        /// Prevents the window from receiving the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message.
        /// </summary>
        NoSendChanging = 0x0400,

        /// <summary>
        /// Retains the current size (ignores the cx and cy parameters).
        /// </summary>
        NoSize = 0x0001,

        /// <summary>
        /// Retains the current Z order (ignores the hWndInsertAfter parameter).
        /// </summary>
        NoZOrder = 0x0004,

        /// <summary>
        /// Displays the window.
        /// </summary>
        ShowWindow = 0x0040
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);


    internal static void MoveToScreen(this Window window, Monitor next, bool fullScreen = false)
    {
        if (fullScreen)
        {
            SetWindowPos(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle, (IntPtr)SpecialWindowHandles.Top,
                (int)next.NativeBounds.Left, (int)next.NativeBounds.Top, (int)next.NativeBounds.Width, (int)next.NativeBounds.Height, SetWindowPosFlags.ShowWindow);
            return;
        }

        SetWindowPos(new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle, (IntPtr)SpecialWindowHandles.Top,
            (int)next.NativeBounds.Left, (int)next.NativeBounds.Top, (int)window.Width, (int)window.Height, SetWindowPosFlags.ShowWindow);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//targetMonitor is a custom class which holds the details about a screen,
//such as bounds, name, scale, etc.

this.MoveToScreen(targetMonitor);
```